# How do replace a string with '\' with '\\' in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, replace, str-replace

For example I want to take input the absolute path from the user like "C:\Users\User\Desktop" and change it to "C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop" but when I do the following:

`path = input("Enter path: ")`
and
`path = path.replace("\", "\\")`

it throws syntax error as the escape sequence of `\\` is triggered. How do I bypass this and achieve the replace?

**Correction: It takes input and adjusts itself! There is no need to do such a thing as mentioned above...**

Comment: use raw strings `r"\"`

Comment: @rdas `r"\"` is illegal in Python.

Answer (score 6):

Backslash is a control character in Python, meaning that a single backslash in your Python script does not, by itself, mean a single literal backslash.  You may escape it to make this work:

```
path = path.replace("\\", "\\\\")
```

In this case, `\\` represents a single literal backslash, and `\\\\`, the replacement, represents two literal backslahses.

Answer (score -1):

You can use

```
os.path.join() or 
path=input()
path='//'.join(path.split('/'))
```

Comment: Oh I figured it out... Python does the work by itself... Thanks

Comment: then you give upvote